# Script for updating files differences between computers

Tags: linux, ssh, synchronization

I have desktop computer and a notebook where I work modifying the same files with the same programs. I want to automatically synchronize the changes I make in any of those.
I'm wondering if there exists some already coded script that makes this job or, if there isn't any, the commands to compare the creation of the files of interests in both computers via ssh and replaces the older ones with the newer ones.

Example:
I modify /home/text.txt file in the notebook and before shutting it off I want to execute a script that automatically saves the text.txt file into my desktop computer /home/text.txt becoase one is newer than the other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bi-directional synchronizer `unison` comes to mind, and doesn't require internet access (although it does require a network connection between your two systems).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to use [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/).
Install it on both, create an account, and login. Problem solved.